# send redirect from java to Angular 8

Tags: java, angular, maven, redirect, servlets

I am using Java, Maven and Angular 8 for my current project.

I have a problem with redirecting an url from the backend to the frontend.

In the backend I use the `sendRedirect()` method from `HttpServletResponse` with an url string.

The goal is to use this sendRedirect url string to navigate in the Angular 8 app to the desired page via **app-routing.module.ts**

At the moment, I am sending the url string to frontend but the response that I get is a **404**.

How can I solve this to make it work as I mentioned as the goal?

Comment: Please follow stackoverflow guidelines while posting questions. Provide sample code and approaches that you have tried for fuurthur analysis.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you can only access the redirected url directly but when the same, identical url is provided via a redirect you get a 404?

Comment: @Kyan from the backend sending a url to to navigate gives a 404